# Unable to build and run ARSimpleProj with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, artoolkit

I'm new to AR and currently I've wanted to try out ARToolKit with Android Studio.

When I tried to open the example, which is ARSimpleProg

It has error saying : Plugin with id 'com.android.model.application' not found.

and also Gradle Project Sync Failed

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 and I've already changed my Gradle as below

[image]

Since it says it must have Android Plugin Version 2.1.2

and also I've change the Gradle version to 2.13 because I read it from this [website](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility)

Comment: The plugin should be named `com.android.application`. It's not clear why you are using an experimental Gradle feature

Comment: For more details on that.  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks! that was actually the original code that was retrieved from ARToolKit example

Comment: Can you please share links to that so we can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: @cricket_007 the example was provided together with the andoird SDK of ARToolKit, I've downloaded from her https://artoolkit.org/download-artoolkit-sdk

Answer (score 0):

please follow the instructions from here to get setup with the native development with ARToolKit using Android Studio:
http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_native

Also have a look at the question here:
[Gradle DSL cannot find sources()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702437/gradle-dsl-cannot-find-sources/38714288#38714288)

ARToolKit uses the gradle experimental plugin for building the code. The gradle script structure with the 'model' upfront is correct. This comes from the build.gradle (ARSimpleProj) file.

You need to build and setup your environment as instructed in the ARToolKit documentation.

Hope that helps